# matrix multiplication but sum of min() instead of sum of product

Tags: tensorflow, math, matrix, linear-algebra, tensorflow.js

I'm looking for a sequence of matrix operations that achieve the following:

given for example the input matrix

```
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
2 2 4 4
3 0 5 5
```

Will output the following:

```
0 0 0  0
0 4 4  4
0 4 12 10
0 4 10 13
```

What should happen?
Well knowing how matrix multiplication works, there is only 1 small diferrence to explain. Matrix multiplication works like this:
[image: Matrix multiplication]
*resultMatrix[row][column] = sum(A[row][every column x]*B[row x][column])*

The sequence of operations should do the following:

*resultMatrix[row][column] = sum(min(A[row][every column x],B[row x][column]))*

Where B is the transpose of A.

**What TensorflowJS functions can I use to achieve this?**

Thanks @jdehesa for your answer, when using the code in your answer on a 2881x2980 shape, I apparently hit a limit and TensorFlowJS throws the following error:

```
Error: Requested texture size [193027x128140] greater than WebGL maximum on this browser / GPU [16384x16384].
    at validateTextureSize (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at createAndConfigureTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at createFloat32MatrixTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.createFloat32MatrixTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.acquireTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.acquireTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.uploadToGPU (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.compileAndRun (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.minimum (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at ENV.engine.runKernel.$a (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
```

Any batch/optimization ideas?

Comment: Where is matrix B in the example you gave?

Comment: @scai "Where B is the transpose of A."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```js
const a = tf.tensor2d(
  [[0, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 4, 4],
   [3, 0, 5, 5]]);
const b = a.transpose();
const m = a.expandDims(-1).minimum(b);
const result = m.sum(1);

result.print();
```

Output:

```
"Tensor
    [[0, 0, 0 , 0 ],
     [0, 4, 4 , 3 ],
     [0, 4, 12, 10],
     [0, 3, 10, 13]]"
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot!

Comment: When using this code on a 2881x2980 shape, TensorFlowJS throws the following error:

Error: Requested texture size [193027x128140] greater than WebGL maximum on this browser / GPU [16384x16384].
    at createFloat32MatrixTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.createFloat32MatrixTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.acquireTexture (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.uploadToGPU (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.compileAndRun (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at e.minimum (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)
    at ENV.engine.runKernel.$a (tf-core.esm.js?45ef:17)

Any batch/optimization ideas?

Comment: @Vinzentz The problem is this solution creates an intermediate `N x N x N` tensor, so it does take a lot of memory. I'm not sure if there is any other good way to do the same thing but with this method the only thing you can do is reduce the batch size really...